# Android Facebook Login, if not logged start login activity else start another activity

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I have implemented `Facebook Login` to my Android App and it is working OK,

I have implemented Code for `OnSuccess()` to start new `activity` after successful registration using `Facebook`, now I need to be able to verify, whenever I run the app, if the user is already registered and not have to take them through `Facebook loginactivity` again if they already registered and just start main `activity` instead.

Please advise how I can track this. Thanks

Comment: post what you did till now `postyourcode`

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to check if the user is logged in or not.

```
    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        return accessToken != null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created this method `

```
public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        boolean loggedIn = false;
        AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

        if (accessToken != null) {
            loggedIn = true;

        } else {
            loggedIn=false;


        }
        return loggedIn;
    }`
```

And then I used it to check if successful login here

`

```
public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        if(isLoggedIn()!=false){
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
            mTxtFirstName = profile.getFirstName();
            mProfID = profile.getId();

            intent.putExtra("name", mTxtFirstName);
            intent.putExtra("profileID", mProfID);
            startActivity(intent);
        }`
```

Now that the user has logged in, I don't want to keep coming back to LoginActivity each time they start the app..